# Gathering data from generic static method?

Tags: java

I have problem.

How to gather data from static method `makeFrom` and pass it to `filter` method then pass it to `map` method without creating static field so I can use this class like this `makeFrom(src).filter(filter).map(mapper)`?

```
public class ListMaker<N, T> {

private static List<?> newList;  // its the only way?

static <T> List<T> makeFrom(List<T> list){

    List<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();
    newList.addAll(list);
    return newList;     

}

public List<T> filter(Filter<T> filter){

    ???  here I need newList returned in makeFrom

}

public List<T> map(Mapper<N,T> map){
    ???

}

}
```

Comment: Hi Seteve, can you be more specific about the your requirement on what is that you are trying and what is stopping you.

Comment: Your local `newList` hides the static one. It isn't even used.

Comment: In order to call `filter`, the `makeFrom` method must return a `ListMaker<N, T>` instance.

Comment: You cannot chain those calls, because `makeFrom` returns a `List` and not a `ListMaker`. In fact, all those chain-methods should return a ListMaker. Then you need something like a terminator to get the list - like `List toList()` or `List build()` ...

Comment: In case if you want to do 3 of the mentioned operations better call the `filter` and `map` functions from inside your `makeForm` and return the final list

Comment: So if my makeFrom method return ListMaker object how can I use it in filter method?

Comment: The filter method will be called on the ListMaker instance that is returned by makeFrom.

Comment: By the way: Why reinvent the wheel and not use streams?

Comment: I'm just trying to make kind of stream-working class on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically a builder pattern. You can make it much more complex than my example - if you want to force an order of the calls or must prevent an operation is called after another has already been called, for example.

It should look something like this:

```
public class ListMaker<T> { // no guarantee about the generics, didn't have a compiler here.

    private List<?> newList;

    // CTOR: initialize internal state.
    private ListMaker( List<T> list ){
         newList = new ArrayList<T>();
         newList.addAll(list);
    }

    // Factory method: Create ListMaker
    public static <T> ListMaker<T> makeFrom(List<T> list){
        ListMaker lm = new ListMaker( list );
        return lm;   
    }

    // apply filter
    public ListMaker<T> filter(Filter<T> filter){
        newList = filter.apply(newList); // <- interface? Just making something up
        return this;
    }

    // apply mapper
    public ListMaker<T> map(Mapper<N,T> map){
        newList = map.apply(newList); // <- interface? Just making something up
        return this;
    }

    // terminator to retrieve the result
    public List<T> toList(){
        return newList;
    }
}
```

Note: without further knowledge about all the interfaces and signatures, I had to make some things up. But you'll get the gist of it, I hope.

This can then be used like:

```
List<String> strList = ListMaker.makeFrom(source)  // now we have an instance of ListMaker
                                                   // on which we call the rest
                                .filter(myFilter)  // modifys newList and returns itself
                                .map(myMapping)    // modifys newList and returns itself
                                .toList();         // now we can return the result List.
```